# jQuery select only direct parent with the same class as grandparent(s)

Tags: jquery, html, select

I am having problems selecting a direct parent of an element that has the same class as the parents of that parent.

```
<div class="myClass">
  <div class="myClass">
    <div class="myClass">
      <div class="myElement" data-background="background_color_1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So only the direct parent can have a classes added to it from the data-background value.

```
$('.myElement').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var data_bg = that.attr('data-background');
    that.parents().closest().addClass('column-bg').addClass(data_bg);
});
```

Tried it with closest only, parents and closest, if I leave parents() alone it applies it all. Can someone help me.
Thanks

Comment: Use `that.parent().addClass(...`. or `that.closest('.myClass').addClass(...` if it won't always be the direct parent.

Comment: `.closest()` needs an argument, the selector to look for.

Comment: I can't figure out which elements you're trying to select. All the ancestors have the same class. Which ones should be selected, which should be excluded?

Comment: @JohnS forgot to say that between the parents with the same classes there are more elements, even between myElement and the direct myClass  are some div wrappers. so I tried that.parent('myClass').addClass()
but still doesn't work

Comment: @Barmar trying to select the direct parent myClass traversing up from the myElement

Comment: If there are elements in between, does that mean that you don't want to select the direct parent?

Comment: It would help if your example showed the actual HTML, and then said precisely which elements should be selected. Your description isn't clear, and I'm not sure you understand what "direct parent" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.closest('.myClass')`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). It will get the closest (i.e., first) anscestor that has the class "myClass".

```
$('.myElement').each(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var data_bg = that.attr('data-background');
    that.closest('.myClass').addClass('column-bg').addClass(data_bg);
});
```

Comment: for some reason it still selects other parents with the same class using closest()

Comment: @user2666378 - `.closest()` will never return more than one element when it is called on a single element.

Comment: not sure why the closest didnt work with my approach, but your code definitely did it. Big thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
$('.myElement').filter(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var grandp = parent.parent();
    return grandp.hasClass( parent.attr('class') );
})
parent().addClass(......);
```

```js
$('.myElement').filter(function(){
        return $(this).parent().parent().hasClass( $(this).parent().attr('class') );
})
.parent().addClass('highlight');
```

```css
div {
  padding: 14px;
}
.myClass {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.highlight {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
  <div class="myClass">
    <div class="myClass">
      <div class="myElement" data-background="background_color_1">GOOD</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  <div class="myClass">
    <div class="myClasss">
      <div class="myElement" data-background="background_color_1">NOT GOOD</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class selector in the argument to `.parents()` to restrict it to parents that have the class of the grandparent.

```
var grandparentClass = that.parent().parent().attr("class")
that.parents("." + grandparentClass).addClass("column-bg " + data_bg)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood tue question. This way all parents receive an extra class until 1 parent doesn't have the class 'myClass'

```
var element = $('div.myElement');

$(document).ready(function() {
    while (element.parent().hasClass('myClass')) {
        element.parent().addClass('added');
        element = element.parent();
    }
});
```

=- Snippet with some colors -=

```js
var element = $('div.myElement');
color = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];
var i = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    while (element.parent().hasClass('myClass')) {
        element.parent().addClass('added');        
        element = element.parent();
        element.css('background-color', color[i]);
        i++;
    }
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
    <div class="myClass">
        <div class="myClass">
            <div class="myElement"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```